# Question moving from Magento 1.x to 2.x - what to do with extensions

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

i am moving from Magento 1.x to 2.x - I have a lot of custom build extensions from which my business is dependent on - without them I can not work...

So, obviously when we are going to migrate to 2.x, these extensions will stop functioning properly...

Is there any possibility to fix these extensions with little recode? Or they must be totally rewritten to work ?

Is there any 3rd party support that would make these extensions work on new Magento version?

Please, help. Thanks.

Comment: The extension must be rewritten totally, if you want the 3rd party support you can contact on this email: partab@tekglide.com

Comment: If you want to move data from your custom built extensions, we can help you by using custom code. Visit our website for more details on Magento 1 to Magento 2 upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a list of extension that implemented,
2. It is better to filter which extensions that you gonna need or you don't need it anymore after the upgrade.
3. Find the source of every extension that you want to implement (whether you buy it or develop on yourself or third party vendor)
4. If the extension you buy and modify from extension developer company like amasty, magecomp, fme, mageplaza, etc. Then, it may be the best that you contact them first and check is there any version fit into 2.x, you may do less recode if you purchase the support.
5. If the extension develop on yourself, yes you may do want to check the change log and doing a recode.
6. If someone else developed specialized extension for you, then you might need to contact them to do a less recode.

I've been doing this from 2.2.x to 2.3.x,but if you want to find any third party to doing it for you, there are lot of them. Some that I've been / will be working in near future with : https://www.emizentech.com/ , https://www.limecommerce.com/ , https://amasty.com/magento-services.html , https://magecomp.com/magento-services.html , and https://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-services.html